# Should I use the OS socket buffer as a message queue?

Tags: java, networking, nio

This question concerns the design of a Java application for reading and processing large amounts of data from a few dozen UDP sockets, but I think it is relevant for other languages and environments.

I've seen network applications like the one described above have dedicated thread(s) for reading data off the socket buffer as quickly as possible, requeuing it inside the application and then processing it in a separate thread.

Is there anything wrong with leaving the data in the socket buffer until your processing thread is ready to receive the next piece of data?  Is there any advantage to reading the data quickly and requeuing inside the application?

If the processing logic is not fast enough, the buffers will fill up.  But if the processing logic is too slow to handle the inbound data, it seems like it does not matter where the data is queued.  In case of a sudden spike in inbound data, the socket buffers should be large enough to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer size for received UDP packets in the network stack is limited. If the buffer is full, some packets will be lost.

If the software handling UDP packets know, that it may need some time before it is able to process the packet, it makes sense to read the packet as soon as possible, relieving the network stack buffer and rather implement your own buffer or queue for the packets, in which they can be cached until processing resources are actually available.